# Find the equation of the tangent at the point (x,y) on each of the curves: $x^2 + y^2 = c^2$ (Using the Limits Only!)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the equation of the tangent at the point (x,y) on each of the curves:

$$x^2 + y^2 = c^2$$

**This question is from The Book 'Differential Calculus for Beginners' by Joseph Edwards, given on page 13 of Chapter - 2.**

This question was to be **Evaluated using Limits (using Infinite Series) and not Derivatives.**

Here's my try:

$$x^2 + y^2 = c^2 \Rightarrow y = \pm \sqrt{c^2 - x^2}$$
Let's Go only with the Positive ones for now:

$$\lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0} [\frac{((1-(\frac{x+h}{c})^2)^\frac 1 2 - ((1-(\frac{x}{c})^2)^\frac 1 2 ))c}{h}]$$

Which I using the Binomial Expansion got this reduced to:

$$\lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac l h(\frac{x^2 - h^2 - 2xh}{2c^2}+(...)\space \space )$$

Here the $(...)$ is some binomial expansion for the series (also l here is also some series which will is kept so as to be used in future if needed) which will be eliminated once the value of $h$ is just plugged.

So, I don't seem to get the solution equation which is: $Xx + Yy = c^2$

Is this the right direction? I dun think that this is a function, so I'm not sure that this method is correct either!
**Note: I don't think that the equation above has been made using that equation,but I don't know anything about it either. $x$ and $y$ are the points whose tangent we want to find **

Comment: After "binomial expansion" you have an expression that goes to infinity as $h\to0.$ Did you miss a chance to cancel the term $x^2/(2c^2)$? For that matter, why did you write the derivative as a limit rather than using other theorems about derivatives to find the derivative? That seems like the hard way to solve the problem.

Comment: @DavidK The book I'm following is for Beginners, So, I've just learned the Limits and I'm learning how to calculate the derivative using 1st principle (using limits using expansions), since you understand the question properly, please can you help me with it, I desperately need to know to do this one using the limit expansions

Comment: Have you studied conic sections? Or, at least circles?

Comment: @MayankM. No, I need solutions in Limits only!

Comment: If you absolutely _must_ find the derivative by first principles (forbidden to use even the chain rule and power rule--how absurd!), then you should do it again but _write down_ all the steps you skipped--first to say exactly what function you're taking a derivative of, then what each binomial expansion looks like (there are two!), and then how you put them together. You can edit all of that into the question so people can see if you are doing it right.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Well, I could show you a very simple way of finding tangent using limits using a formula in conic sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $y(x) = \sqrt{c^2 - x^2}.\;$ The tangent at any point of the courbe for  $\;x\in (-c,c)$ exists and has the slope 
$$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} \left[\frac{((1-(\frac{x+h}{c})^2)^\frac 1 2 - ((1-(\frac{x}{c})^2)^\frac 1 2 ))c}{h}\right]$$ as written by OP. Compute this limit 
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{c^2-(x+h)^2} - \sqrt{c^2-x^2}}{h}&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{c^2-(x+h)^2 - c^2+x^2}{h\left(\sqrt{c^2-(x+h)^2} + \sqrt{c^2-x^2}\right)}\\&=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-2x}{\sqrt{c^2-(x+h)^2} + \sqrt{c^2-x^2}}\\&=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{c^2-x^2}}=\frac{-x}{y}\end{aligned}$$
Can you finish from this?

At $(-c,0)$ and $(0,c)$ are tangents vertical, so their equations are $x=-c,\;x=c,\;$ respectively. These also can be rewritten in the form $Xx + Yy = c^2.$

For the half-circle under $x-$axis given by $y(x) = -\sqrt{c^2 - x^2}$ we obtain the equation analogously.

Comment: How you computed limits in last step? Isn't that 0/0?

Comment: I think your answer should be $\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{c^2-x^2}}$

Comment: Which step do you mention? After $h \over h$ disappears, we can replace $h$ by $0.$

Comment: No, the value in denominator is multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 0):

The courbes are circles centered at $(0,0),$ with radius $r.$
The tangent at a point of the circle is perpendicular to the corresponding diameter.
Thus $(x_0,y_0)$ are not only coordinates of a point of tangency, but also coordinates of the vector normal to the tangent at this point.
Hence the equation of the tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$ is $xx_0+yy_0=c.$ Uploading $x=x_0,y=y_0$ gives $c=r^2.$

The equation is $$xx_0+yy_0=r^2.$$

Comment: Can you do this using the limits using the first principle?